# Migrating the existing react app from "create-react-app" to "parcel"

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, create-react-app, parceljs, build-tools

I have a react project on which I've used `create-react-app` and now I have come to know about the advantages of using `parcel` so now I want to use the `parcel` for building the rest of the project.

I installed parcel as dev dependency and started the server, It says that index.html is not reachable for that I added the start script `"start": "parcel ./src/index.html"` but now its giving another error

```
Server running at http://localhost:1234

 Build failed.

@parcel/core: Failed to resolve '%PUBLIC_URL%/logo.svg' from './public/index.html'

@parcel/resolver-default: Cannot load file './%PUBLIC_URL%/logo.svg' in './public'.
```

This is the GitHub repo: https://github.com/olifarhaan/griha-milan

This is the live link just in case you want to check: https://griha-milan.vercel.app/

I tried adding `/logo.svg`  instead of  `./%PUBLIC_URL%/logo.svg` . Also, I'm using the env variable in the index.html for the title and description. I am not able to figure out how to show the environment variable there.

Answer (score 0):

If this were me, I'd create a brand new `parcel` project, then copy `src` and other assets into the new project.  Copy the `.git` over as well, then you have a clone of your existing repository but in a new parcel project.  Avoid bringing over any CRA-related elements.